# R: Split a Vector into Some Overlapping Sub-vectors with Its First Element being Rebounded

Tags: r, vector, split

I want to split a parent sub-vectors such that these conditions hold:

1. Each sub-vector has equal and constant length `l`.
2. The sub-vectors overlap one another with `l -1`
3. Number of sub-vector is given as `length(ts) - l + 2`
4. The last sub-vector should include the first element of the parent vector as its last sub-element.

.

```
ts <- 1:11 # the parent vector
l <- 7 # constant length of sub-vectors to be
m <- length(ts) - l + 1 # number of sub-vector to be
split(t(embed(ts, m))[m:1,], 1:m)
```

When I tried this (with `m <- length(ts) - l + 1`) I got my `l = 7` like I want but `m = 5` instead of `m = 6` like I want.

```
#$`1`
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7

#$`2`
#[1] 2 3 4 5 6 7 8

#$`3`
#[1] 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

#$`4`
#[1]  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

#$`5`
#[1]  5  6  7  8  9 10 11
```

When I tried this (with `m <- length(ts) - l + 2`) I got `m = 6` like I want but `l = 6` instead of `l = 7`.

```
ts <- 1:11 # the parent vector
l <- 7 # constant length of sub-vectors to be
m <- length(ts) - l + 2 # number of sub-vector to be
split(t(embed(ts, m))[m:1,], 1:m)
```

This is what I got

```
#$`1`
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6

#$`2`
#[1] 2 3 4 5 6 7

#$`3`
#[1] 3 4 5 6 7 8

#$`4`
#[1] 4 5 6 7 8 9

#$`5`
#[1]  5  6  7  8  9 10

#$`6`
#[1]  6  7  8  9 10 11
```

**What I Want**

```
#$`1`
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7

#$`2`
#[1] 2 3 4 5 6 7 8

#$`3`
#[1] 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

#$`4`
#[1]  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

#$`5`
#[1]  5  6  7  8  9 10 11

#$`6`
#[1]  6  7  8  9 10 11  1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```r
ts <- 1:11 # the parent vector
l <- 7 # constant length of sub-vectors to be
m <- length(ts) - l + 2 # number of sub-vector to be

library(magrittr)
lapply(1:m, function(i){
  c(0, rep(ts, 4)) %>% # Adding leading zero (cut in first iter; repeat a few times to not run out if we increase m
    tail(-i) %>% # Cut first i elements (including added zero)
    head(l) # Retain first l of the remaining part
})
```

Answer (score 2):

If it only has to work for parent vectors that contain sequences of integers from 1 (like `1:10`, `1:8`) then this should do:

```
ts <- 1:11
l <- 7
m <- length(ts) - l + 2


lapply(1:m, function(x) {
  y <- x:(x+l-1)
  y <- ifelse(y>max(ts), y-max(ts), y)} #here you make sure that 12 becomes 1 etc.
       )
```

But if you want this to work for any type of atomic vector (e.g. the letters A, B, C...K) , do this:

```
ts2 <- LETTERS[1:11]
l <- 7
m <- length(ts) - l + 2

# the output from the code above is stored to be used as index
idx <- lapply(1:m, function(x) {
  y <- x:(x+l-1)
  y <- ifelse(y>length(ts2), y-length(ts2), y)}
)

# apply index to the parent vector
lapply(idx, function(x) ts2[x])
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use `filter`:

```
ts <- 1:11 
l <- 7

lapply(seq_len(length(ts) - l + 2), function(i) {
  p <- rep(0, l)
  p[i] <- 1
  res <- c(stats::filter(rev(ts), filter = p, 
                         circular = TRUE, sides = 1))
  rev(res)[seq_len(l)]
})
#[[1]]
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
#
#[[2]]
#[1] 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
#
#[[3]]
#[1] 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
#
#[[4]]
#[1]  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
#
#[[5]]
#[1]  5  6  7  8  9 10 11
#
#[[6]]
#[1]  6  7  8  9 10 11  1
```

Answer (score 2):

Fill a matrix with appropriate dimensions, index, and split

```
asplit(
  matrix(ts, nrow = length(ts) + 1, ncol = length(ts) - l + 1)[1:(l + 1), ],
  MARGIN = 2)

#[[1]]
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
#
#[[2]]
#[1] 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
#
#[[3]]
#[1] 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
#
#[[4]]
#[1]  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
#
#[[5]]
#[1]  5  6  7  8  9 10 11
#
#[[6]]
#[1]  6  7  8  9 10 11  1
```